# Обработка исключений ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net-mvc, исключения

При добавлении модели в базу данных, если некоторые поля в модели == `null`, то будет исключение `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`, которое возвращает код 500. Как правильно сделать обработку этого исключения?

Мои варианты:

1. Сделать проверку всех полей модели в контроллере, если какие-нибудь поля == `null`, то писать об этом во view. Мне не нравится этот вариант, тк полей может быть 1000 и придется писать для каждого проверку.
2. С помощью `try`/`catch` отлавливать ошибки в `Data Access Layer`. Тут вопрос, насколько это эффективно, тк происходит лишний запрос к бд, без которого можно обойтись.

Как правильно реализовать обработку исключений при добавлении модели в базу данных?

У меня есть обработка `HttpException` в **Global.asax.cs**:

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
        var currentController = string.Empty;
        var currentAction = string.Empty;
        var currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

        if (currentRouteData != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
            {
                currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
            {
                currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            }
        }


        var ex = Server.GetLastError();

        log.Error(ex.Message);

        var controller = new ErrorController();
        var routeData = new RouteData();           
        var action = "General";



        if (ex is HttpException)
        {
            switch (((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode())
            {
                case 500:
                    action = "ServerError";
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", action);
                    break;
                case 404:
                    action = "NotFound";
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", action);
                    break;
                default:
                    action = "General";
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", action);
                    break;

            }
        }

        httpContext.ClearError();
        httpContext.Response.Clear();
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = ex is HttpException ? ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() : 500;
        httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
        routeData.Values["action"] = action;
        Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        controller.ViewData.Model = new Exception(ex.ToString());
        ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));

        }
```

Но представление для 500 оно почему-то не возвращает и ошибка появляется после запроса к бд, а я бы хотел без запроса к бд справиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в модель атрибуты
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

и проверьте, на валидность.

```
if(!myModel.IsValid)
 //код обработки ошибки
```

Comment: Благодарю! Это именно то, что мне нужно.